# C++ RVO: when it happens?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvo, nrvo

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c795a5d2bb91ae32

```
#include <iostream>
struct X {
    X(const char *) { std::cout << 1; }
    X(const X &) { std::cout << 2; }
    X(X &&) { std::cout << 3; }
};
X f(X a) {
    return a;
}
X g(const char * b) {
    X c(b);
    return c;
}

int main() {
    f("hello"); // 13
    g("hello"); // 1
}
```

Is there any difference in the last line of function `f(X a)`:
`return a;` instead of `return std::move(a);`?

Is it true that function `f` doesn't have RVO but `g` has NRVO?

Comment: IIRC, using `return std::move(a);` foils RVO; true RVO involves neither move nor copy constructors, but `std::move(a)` means construction is required, because you violated the rules for NRVO.

Comment: Stephan T. Lavavej explains this in his "Don't help the Compiler" talk

Comment: One question per question please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any difference in the last line of function f(X a): return a; instead of return std::move(a);?

No. `a` is a local variable of the function, so `return a` can move from it.

> Is it true that function `f` doesn't have RVO but `g` has NRVO?

Correct. Named elision never applies to function parameters; it only applies to local variables that are not function parameters.